# First RPC call to HRD or CloudSQL freezes my app for 2-3 seconds

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, eclipselink, datanucleus

The first call (**RPC**) to my **HRD** datastore or **CloudSQL** freezes for **2-3** seconds (see attached screens) - this works so for every request to my app.

There are 2 request types (steps) on the attached screens:

1. Send authenticate (POST) data, validate (CloudSQL) and generate/store an token (HRD),
2. Send the received token (POST), get original data (from HRD) and run step 1.

The first one takes about **8-12** seconds to respond (this is the problem)
and the second only **500ms**.

The **second** one is more complex, it gets an existing token from HRD (using Memcache on *datanucleus.cache.level2* and *datanucleus.cache.queryResults*), translates it into authentication data and executes the steps from **first** request type.

I can't figure out what's the problem. Please, help me out.

**Random appstats screen for step 1:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO6k4.png

**Random appstats screen for step 2:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6urka.png

Comment: and your JPA provider is?

Comment: Hi @DataNucleus , for HRD - Datanucleus 3.1.3, for CloudSQL - EclipseLink 2.5

Comment: and when you look in the log